# how to implement tap gesture in webview to display html not website

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need my web view to be tappable and scrolable. Once I implement on touch the scroll doesnt work. This way i managed to get it working however now i dont know how to make the web view tappable? the ButtonPress does nothing and if i use Move then i am just scrolling

This my my render in mu droid project

```
class ExtendedWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            WebView _webView;
 
            public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    _webView = view;
                    if (_xwebView != null)
                    {

                        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                        _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);
                    }
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _xwebView = e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView;
            _webView = Control;

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient());
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.Touch -= ControlOnTouch;
                Control.ScrollChange -= ControlOnScrollChange;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Touch += ControlOnTouch;
                Control.ScrollChange += ControlOnScrollChange;
            }
        }

        private void ControlOnScrollChange(object sender, ScrollChangeEventArgs scrollChangeEventArgs)
        {
            if (scrollChangeEventArgs.ScrollY > 0 && scrollChangeEventArgs.OldScrollY == 0)
            {
                Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }

        private void ControlOnTouch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            // Executing this will prevent the Scrolling to be intercepted by parent views
            switch (e.Event.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.ButtonPress:
                    Console.WriteLine("press");
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Mask:
                    Console.WriteLine("mask");
                    break;
            }
            // Calling this will allow the scrolling event to be executed in the WebView
            Control.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the gesture recognizer on your webview, you can use the **Focused** event like following . It will been invoked when you tap the **WebView** .

```
var wb = new WebView
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Source = "xxx",
};

wb.Focused += (sender, event) =>
{
   
   //Handle your logic here!
   wb.Unfocus();
 };
```

**Unfocus()** is used if you want to implement your logic everytime the webview is tapped.

Comment: I have tried this before but i didnt managed to get this work. This is simply implemented on the back of the content page in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, what the means of didn't work . Did the scroll work ?

Comment: i will let zou know i am just implementing it, i am not sure, i think that either the scroll didn't work or it didn't get fired. I have implemented so many different ways lately that i dont remember what was the outcome. However i couldn't find any proper documentation on this focused event or pannedcommand so i dont think the implementation was correct

Comment: OMG! it wokrs! you saved my life! Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: Happy coding :)